# how to unwind generic arrays in typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to implement MongoDB style array "unwinds" in typescript.
I want to implement a generic function that returns the correct answer with well defined types.

I provided an example problem with the expected result below.

I don't understand the syntax to

1. determine the type of the unwound items returned from an input generic type
2. omit the key that contains the nested array

```js
describe('unwindByKey', () => {
// please help #1
  type UnwindItemType = <T, key = key of T> Omit<T, key>

// please help #2
  function unwindByKey<T extends {}, K = keyof T, U>(items: T[], key: K): U[] {
    return items.reduce((accum, item) => {
      const {[key]: keyItems, ...itemRest} = item
      const unwoundItems: UnwindItemType<T, key> = keyItems.map(keyItem => ({
        ...itemRest
        [key]: keyItem,
      })
      return [...accum, ...unwoundItems]
    }, [])
  }

// example problem
  interface DataItem {
    a: number
    b: number[]
  }

  type UnwoundDataItem = UnwindItemType<DataItem, 'b'>

// should make this
  // interface UnwoundDataItem {
  //   a: number
  //   b: number
  // }

  const data: DataItem[] = [
    {a: 0, b: [0, 1, 2]},
    {a: 1, b: [3, 4, 5]},
  ]

  const expectedData: UnwoundDataItem[] = [
    {a: 0, b: 0},
    {a: 0, b: 1},
    {a: 0, b: 2},
    {a: 1, b: 3},
    {a: 1, b: 4},
    {a: 1, b: 5},
  ]

  test('it works', () => {
    const result = unwindByKey(data, 'b')
    expect(result.length).toBe(expectedData.length)
  })

})
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wjXL2m) meet your needs? I could write up an answer if so. If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Yes. This is amazing. Thank you! I'm surprised about the separation of the generic function prototype and the implementation. Can you provide a reference that talks about this separation?

Comment: @cyrf - https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads